# Installing update2 for VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, package

I installed update2 for VS2015. This took a long time. Eventually I had to go home with my PC and decided to hibernate my PC. When I got I home I continued the installation. The install seemed to be fine but at the very end listed a whole bunch of errors, all about not being able to find a file (no file name provided). I can see that the install did install a whole bunch of stuff, but now I need to worry about what did not install.

When I attempt to re-run vs2015.2.exe it states that there is nothing to do and will do nothing even when I select either the 'Reset defaults' or 'Select All' options.

How can I re-install for my peace of mind?

Comment: You need to uninstall the old one completely. Unfortunately there is no easy way of getting rid of an existing Visual Studio installation completely. The installer almost never works.

Comment: If I uninstall all software packages from windows programs and features that were installed by update2 and I run it again do you think that would work? Dumb question is it not? Guess all I can do is try.

Answer (score 0):

My pc once crashed while installing Updates from VS2015 and it left some critical damage... I backed up my projects and reïnstalled VS, For me this was the easiest and fastest way to solve the problem, other wise it would probably be an almost impossible job to revert everything back

When the installation was finished i tried again, this time watching over my pc to insure nothing bad would happen again. This solved it on my pc and it Updated just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Just open Control Panel, then click at Uninstall program and select Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.
Select Change and then click on repair.. Visual studio will repair itself and then you can install your update 2 again.

During repair you won't lost projects..

[image: Repair Visual Studio 2015]